# Asp.net MVC Redirect to another view from current view page using ajax call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I need to call another view from my current view ,i have tried using ajax call and able to call the action and pass parameter and  that view is getting binded with loaded data ,but still it remains in the same page,I am new to ajax so i wish anyone can guide  me what I am Doing wrong

---

```
 $.ajax({
                                            type: 'GET',
                                            async: false,
                                            url: "@Url.Action("BookingSearchFX", "AddBooking")",
                                            contentType: 'application/json',
                                            data: { id: id },
                                            cache: false,
                                            dataType: "html",
                                            success: function (data) {
                                                SetData(data);
                                            },
                                            error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                                alert("Error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown + " " + httpRequest);
                                            }
                                        });
```

And I have already used another form submit ,so I will not be able to use form submit and tried 
location.href = '@Url.Action("AddBooking", "BookingSearchz")?id=' + id

but it is of no use

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. An ajax call cannot redirect. If you want to redirect, just make a normal submit

Comment: Why doing ajax then? Why not a normal form submit ? But if you absolutely need that behavior, you can do that inside the `success` handler by setting `window.location.href` value (to the new url)

Comment: Success Part is not hitting @Shyju

Comment: @StephenMuecke ,Yes so I am just looking is there any other way to do than ajax

Comment: Just make a normal submit (but I do not understand what you mean by _I have already used another form submit_?

Comment: @StephenMuecke,Really sorry but i have been said that we can't use more than 1 form submit and You are right and thanks for the answer and my apologies for posting this question,i tried a lot  from yesterday night ,but didnt thought about this,thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the success function of your ajax call use below for redireccting to other view:

```
window.location.href = "/controller/action?id=" + id;
```